# W3 library-not working, it seemed so simple

Tags: javascript, html, css

Do you ever look at a code and think it looks so simple?

Like it's just a simple three line code-- "I can't possibly mess this up!", you say, and end up messing it up? Because I did, and it's driving me crazy. Ok not that crazy, but I'm stumped.

I'm making an online portfolio and I wanted it to be multi-paged and realized soon enough that I can't (don't want to) rewrite the header html AND header css into each page. It's not efficient at all.

So I did some research & found W3 Data Includes library

(w3schools.com/lib/w3data.js & w3schools.com/w3css/w3data_includes.asp)

So my header: 
https://jsfiddle.net/nsykep2v/

My index with W3 include:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  blah blah blah
</head>

<script src="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3data.js">
</script>

<body>
  <div w3-include-HTML="header.html"></div>

  <script>
    w3IncludeHTML();
  </script>

  <div id="blah">
    blah blah blah
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Don't bother running it, it's just there to give a sense of where I placed the important stuff.

Note:

- I move the script tag around & no header shows up
- I moved the div    around & no header shows up
- I merged the the script tag so it has src inside of it & still no
  header shows up
- They're all in the same file, right next to each other
- I did some other stuff but it's basically moving around things and trying different syntax I don't think it's worth mentioning

Let me know if more info is needed.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console? My first thought when seeing this is that the method is likely being called before the external JS library has a chance to load.

Comment: Validate your HTML. Script elements can't be between the head and body, it must be in one or the other. Browsers will likely correct that by moving it to a valid place. There are other errors.

Comment: *"I can't possibly mess this up!" you say and end up messing it up?* - Nope: all my code works perfectly first time.

Comment: Well, don't use that W3 library. It is really bad. I used that myself, so trust me.

Comment: @mroach using sublime text, so no error messages.

Comment: @LearnHowToBeTransparent what do you recommend as alternative?

Comment: @RobG Validating now! I didn't know this was a thing. Thanks, I'll let you know if i figured it out

Comment: When @mroach asked about errors in the console, you have to look in the console within the developer tools within browser. There were a ton of issues with what you posted that I fixed in the posted answer in plunker. You can compare for yourself after you view the working plunker.

Comment: @nopenopenope I recommend jQuery. It is great and does all things. Also, you need to install a simple HTTP server and add your files, because JS libraries now need it. You can use this simple webserver chrome extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb?hl=en, choose the folder, and enjoy the result. To see errors in JS, right click, click Inspect, and see the console.

Comment: @LearnHowToBeTransparent—jQuery will not help.

Comment: The problem was that i didn't have a web server software downloaded, in case you're curious. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You obviously have lots of work still to do, but this takes what you had and gets it working -- injecting the separate menu.html into index.html using the stuff you provided:

<kbd>[Answer in Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/F9nM4lmsvJUvrYzqBa61?p=preview)</kbd>

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3data.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  <div w3-include-html="menu.html"></div>

  <script>
    w3IncludeHTML();
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

menu.html:

```
<div class="v_dropdown">
  MENU
</div>

<header class="in_dropdown">
  <div id="filler_hdr" class="header">
    <div id="filler_file"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="articles_hdr" class="header">
    <div id="arcs_tab" class="tab">
      <strong><a href="articles.html">Articles</a></strong>
    </div>
    <div id="arcs_file" class="file"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="projects_hdr" class="header">
    <div id="prj_tab" class="tab">
      <strong><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></strong>
    </div>
    <div id="prj_file" class="file"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="photo_hdr" class="header">
    <div id="photo_tab" class="tab">
      <strong><a href="photos.html">Photography</a></strong>
    </div>
    <div id="photo_file" class="file"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="blog_hdr" class="header">
    <div id="blog_tab" class="tab">
      <strong><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></strong>
    </div>
    <div id="blog_file" class="file"></div>
  </div>

</header>
```

Also, make sure that you are serving up your local files using a web server and not file:// URIs when you are developing locally, as the w3data library will not work unless you serve the files from some sort of a web server.

Further, you have some pretty messed up HTML that you started with. Since it seems you are still learning some HTML basics and just trying to dive in, you might want to validate your HTML. One way to do this is by using an **[online tool like this](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input)**.

Comment: That definitely didn't work; I implemented on my own code & ran it separately by itself--no luck. I thought maybe I don't have JS, but JavaScript is already enabled on my chrome. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @nopenopenope It definitely does work. Did you even click on the 'Answer in plunker' link that I posted in the answer?  I even ran it on my iPhone just now.

Comment: I think my pc is missing something (maybe something I haven't downloaded ?) The Plunker did work well, but I downloaded it and it won't work from my laptop. Is that normal?

Comment: I'm guessing you aren't serving the pages though a webserver (such as IISExpress if you are on a PC running Windows)... You need to run a local webserver to serve up the files with this solution, as that library you want to use retrieves the specified data/file to include using a web request (which must be provided by a webserver).  It would be good for you to go through some very basic tutorials on creating a website and/or web development.

Comment: I apologize for the delay, but yes, it's because I didn't have a web server. I downloaded XAMPP yesterday, it has Apache so it worked well, thanks! If the comment has the solution, do i still mark the main answer with   a check?

Comment: @nopenopenope yes, as there were multiple things, and the code you had didn't work and needed lots of cleanup before it would work, besides installing the web server, which is clarified here.

Comment: The webserver allowed me to use the w3 library, which is what was asked here. I didn't post all my HTML and CSS files, so if it works properly now, does that mean there's still a problem?

Comment: @nopenopenope I edited my answer to put more info at the bottom. Please check it out. In regard to your question, if it's working and producing the results you want, you could just leave things. But by looking at your HTML (both here and in the fiddle you provided), there were lots of issues, such as putting script tag outside of body and head elements...  using a <string> opening tag when you meant <strong> etc...   If I was you, I would clean that up and learn the proper way to do it to help yourself going forward. Take care and happy learning!

Comment: It works but does not get properly styled with css